# How to handle set-like size agnostic input format

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

Let's set up some hypothetical simplified scenario: Each instance $i$ of my imaginary dataset $D=\{i_{1}, \ldots, i_{MAX}\}$ has different number $k_{i}$ of $n$-dimensional vectors as input into my neural network. Each of them will be transformed with $m \times n$ matrix $M$ (so, matrices with same parameters) and acted point-wise with some non-linearity $\sigma_{1}$.

Now there are 2 possibilities I want to consider separately:

1. Case: I want to average all those outputs, thus depending of total number of vectors $k_{i}$.
2. Case: I want to choose 2 subsets (no necessarily mutually disjoint) and average vectors from those subsets.

For the later layers (in both cases) I'd use some the "standard" neural networks architectures and loss functions. Notice, I'll probably go with more complex connections than averaging, this is only for the purpose of this technical question.

My questions are:
 1. Is there a "simple" way (meaning: high-level library like
    tensorflow) which allows me to create custom layer with shared
    weights which is also size-agnostic (not size of vectors, but number
    of vectors) Is it possible to parallelise computation like this?

I have some knowledge of tf, but I still didn't use all obscure low-level details and don't know all capabilities of $2.0$ version. Also, I'd know to do this stuff in numpy with handcrafted back-propagation implementation. I'd like to do it in more high level way which will handle backpropagation and parallelisation for me.

I'd like to avoid having tensor of vectors which will be padded, but I'm not sure is it possible. My real problem is more complex but has same characteristics: I need to use same weights on differently connected layers, and I would handle normalization of the input to the following layers to the same scale manually (i.e. with "normal" averaging or weighted attention-like averaging,...). Not always I'd connect all vectors from first layers to all from second. It needs to be flexible for each instance of data.

So, in short: I want to reuse the same weight matrices but connect them differently for each instance of dataset. I want to do it in framework which already has automatic differentiation/backpropagation and parallelisation. Is it possible?

Does eager execution in tf help in solving problems like this? I guess nothing could be done with prebuilt computation graphs in 1.x versions.